# ナビゲーションバーに画像をボタンとして追加し、動作させないまま半透明にもしない方法

Tags: objective-c, ios8, iphone

ナビゲーションバーの右端にアイコンのように画像を貼り付けたいです。
今考えられる実現方法としては、iPhoneアプリのアイコンに使用する
画像をボタンとして下記のコードに組み込むことです。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ナビゲーションバー右端にボタンの追加及び設定
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(hoge) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button]; //右側に設定する場合

    button.enabled = NO; // disableに設定。これで押せなくなる。
}
```

画像（ボタンとしてですが）が追加され、ボタンとしての挙動もしなくなりましたが、
enabledにした為にアイコン画像が半透明になってしまいました。
ボタンとしての挙動をさせず、かつ、アイコン画像を半透明にしない方法を
ご教示いただけないでしょうか。以上、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ナビゲーションバー右端にボタンの追加及び設定
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small@2x.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: anImage];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: imageView]; //右側に設定する場合
}
```

わざわざボタンを持ってくることはないと思います。ご確認ください。
ただ、ナビゲーションバーにある「なにか」をタップしても、なにも起こらないというのは、ユーザインターフェイスとしては、まずいと思うのですが、いかがですか？自己満足なアプリ、ユーザに不親切なアプリは、Appleの審査でリジェクトされる可能性があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ただ、`UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView imageNamed: anImage];`だとエラーが出ました。`UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage];`だとうまくいきました。Appleの審査につきましても注意しておきます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ごめんなさい。回答のほうを修正しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

```
buton.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO; // デフォルトはYES
```

を利用することで、ボタンを無効にしたときに自動的に画像の色が調整されるのを抑制できます。

[UIButton　Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/adjustsImageWhenDisabled)も参照してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、YESだと半透明のままでした。NOにすると、色が調整されるのを抑制できました。

Comment: 逆でした…申し訳ありません、訂正してお詫びします。このケースだと役に立たないかもしれませんが、StoryBoardやInterfaceBuilderからでも設定はできます。また、`adjustsImageWhenDisabled`を`NO`にしても`-imageNamed:forState:`でdisableの状態の画像を設定することができます。